# mp3splt bsed on time and silence

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

How can I split an mp3 into 3 min chunks with the closest silence place/mark.

```
mp3splt -t 3.0 -a -p th=-50,min=1,rm audobook.mp3
```

I tried the above but still mp3splt split the mp3 file into 3-min chucks even if the if the speaker is talking and the next silence is at min 3.02.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can adjust the `gap` value which determines how much time is valid to go over or under a splitpoint to match up with a silence. So for your example if there is a silence at the 3.02 second mark and you want to ensure this captures it you would probably want to set gap to at least 3 seconds.

```
mp3splt -t 3.0 -a -p gap=3,th=-50,min=1,rm audobook.mp3
```